# How to pass parameter to Maven plugin from CLI?

Tags: java, maven, jaxws-maven-plugin

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <id>generate-sei</id>

                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
          <dependencies>...</dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The above XML snippet is from a POM file in a Java project. In this snippet I've defined the jaxws-maven-plugin to use a wsdl file to generate the SEI code and place it in the src/main/java directory. This plugin is bound to the generate-sources phase, and works fine.

I want to make it so that if I issue the plugin directly, using:

```
mvn jaxws:wsimport
```

it should place the files in the above mentioned folder. From the plugins reference site (https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html), I can't figure out how to pass the parameter (sourceDestDir) as a command line argument. Is there someway I can do this?

Comment: Generating code into `src/main` is in general a bad idea...cause it will change code which is committed to a version control...

Comment: Noted, thanks. I have changed this now.

Comment: simply by using `-DparameterKey=parameterValue`

Comment: just an extra hint, if the parameters contain special characters, then you can use `-D"parameter_key"="parameter_value"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

###WARNING /!\

You are trying to generate sources under the source folder `src/main/java`. Unless there is a *very* strong reason, [don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912900/location-of-generated-source-files-for-maven-directory-structure). All generated content should always be placed under the build directory (`target` by default) and not be version-controlled. You can always add the generated sources as source folder using the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-source`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html), if the plugin does not do it already itself.

---

To be able to set parameters directly on the command line, the plugin needs to define a user property. However, the `org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin` does not define a user property for the [`sourceDestDir`](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html#sourceDestDir) parameter. This is noticeable because the documentation does not have a "User Property" set.

You can also find this [in the source code](https://github.com/javaee/metro-jaxws-commons/blob/master/jaxws-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/jvnet/jax_ws_commons/jaxws/MainWsImportMojo.java#L64):

> ```
> @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsimport")
> private File sourceDestDir;
> ```

The `@Parameter` annotation, used to declare the parameter of the Maven plugin, does not have a corresponding [`property`](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.4/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Parameter.html#property()).

As such, you will need to have the following:

1. Define a Maven property `jaxws.sourceDestDir` with a value of `${project.basedir}/src/main/java` with

   ```
   <properties>
     <jaxws.sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</jaxws.sourceDestDir>
   </properties>
   ```

Preferably, you would have `${project.build.directory}/some/path` instead of `src/main/java`.

2. Configure the plugin to use this Maven property:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <sourceDestDir>${jaxws.sourceDestDir}</sourceDestDir>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. If you want to override it, you can now do so directly on the command line with `-Djaxws.sourceDestDir=/my/new/value`. This system property will take precedence over the value of the Maven property.

Comment: Hi Tuanki. Thank you for the extremely comprehensive answer. Just to clarify, any configurations added (using the <configuration> tag) to the POM are not used by the plugin if it's run directly from the CLI, as opposed to being run in the build process in the phase it's bound to?

Comment: @AamirKhan That's where plugin execution, with `<execution>`, come into play. When invoked on the command line, you launch a new custom execution so any configuration that is under `<execution><configuration>` won't be used. However, configuration added in the global `<configuration>` (not under any `<execution>`) will be used. Note that, on the command line, you can also execute a specific existing execution (instead of creating a new one by default) using the `@` syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166538/how-to-execute-maven-plugin-execution-directly-from-command-line.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks @Tunaki!