Is there a way to exclude classes with same package name, but are present in different folders from JaCoCo code coverage report?
This is my folder structure:
- src
  - main
    - java
      - com.chintan.project
    - src-gen
      - com.chintan.project

Is there a way to exclude the classes of package com.chintan.project which are present in src-gen folder, from JaCoCo code coverage report.
The output/target directory of both the folders is same, and I cannot change the package structure or the way in which they are compiled and placed in the output/target directory.
I have tried the below JaCoCo configuration but its not working
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.11</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/src-gen/**/*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/src-gen/**/*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

Can anyone let me know, where am I going wrong or what can be done to solve this problem.

If src-gen contents are generated code, those files shouldn't be inside the src folder. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912900/location-of-generated-source-files-for-maven-directory-structure

Any generation of code should be targeted into target/......
